# Ошибка в String Format

Tags: c#

Есть несложный код, цель которого форматировать и вывести результат с 2 знаками после запятой:

```
double AqPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txb_AqPrice.Text);
double Count = Convert.ToDouble(txb_Count.Text);
double result = (AqPrice * Count);
txb_Money.Text = String.Format(result.ToString(),"0:0.00");
```

Однако форматирования не происходит. Подскажите где ошибся?

Comment: Если почитать профиль ТС, то отвечать, возможно, вообще не стоит...

Comment: @Андрей Поясните мысль

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В примере перепутаны местами аргументы для формата и данных

```
txb_Money.Text = String.Format(result.ToString(),"0:0.00");
```

Если смотреть определение [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static string Format(
    string format,
    object arg0
)
```

Должно было быть наоборот:

```
txb_Money.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", result);
```

`ToString` вызовется автоматически, поэтому его можно не указывать

Comment: Если ToString() вызовется автоматически перед тем как передастся в string.Format(), то, боюсь, на выходе будет не совсем то что мы ожидаем​

Comment: @Андрей, да, не однозначно получилось. Но `String.Format` внутри себя действительно вызывает `ToString` для аргументов, передавая в параметр разобранный формат, если он указан

Comment: словосочетание "его можно не указывать"  наводит на мысли что можно и указать и это не повлияет на результат. Но это не так. Нужно исправить на что-то типа "указывать его не следует".

Comment: @Андрей, тут спорный момент, всегда можно вызвать `ToString` со специальным форматпровайдером, необходимым только для текущего элемента, поэтому следует вызывать ToString или нет, при передаче параметра может зависеть от конкретного кода/задачи

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете написать так: `txb_Money.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", result.ToString("{0:0.00}"));` это избыточно. Да и в вопросе написано просто ToString() без параметров. Это вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: @Андрей - `string.Format` позволяет первым параметром указать `FormatProvider` - он будет применён ко всем параметрам. В `ToString` можно указать собственный форматпровайдер для каждого параметра.